# Multiple instance audio play using Jquery /Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

```
   <form action="downloads_new.php" method="post">
Track Name :- <b>i run this bitch</b><br />
    By :- <a href="profile.php?id=17">DJ Harsha</a><br />
           <div id="22">
        <button class="playback btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play</button>
        <audio src="memberfiles/17/i run this bitch.mp3">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" name="dwn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download MP3</button>
               </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="i run this bitch.mp3" name="file_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="bWVtYmVyZmlsZXMvMTcvaSBydW4gdGhpcyBiaXRjaC5tcDM=" name="link">
</form>
<br>

<form action="downloads_new.php" method="post">
Track Name :- <b>ai se eu tei pego</b><br />
    By :- <a href="profile.php?id=16">DJ perera</a><br />
           <div id="21">
        <button class="playback btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play</button>
        <audio src="memberfiles/16/ai se eu tei pego.mp3">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" name="dwn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download MP3</button>
               </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="ai se eu tei pego.mp3" name="file_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="bWVtYmVyZmlsZXMvMTYvYWkgc2UgZXUgdGVpIHBlZ28ubXAz" name="link">
</form>
<br>

<form action="downloads_new.php" method="post">
Track Name :- <b>Krewella - Live for the night</b><br />
    By :- <a href="profile.php?id=16">DJ perera</a><br />
           <div id="20">
        <button class="playback btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play</button>
        <audio src="memberfiles/16/Krewella - Live for the night.mp3">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" name="dwn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download MP3</button>
               </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="Krewella - Live for the night.mp3" name="file_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="bWVtYmVyZmlsZXMvMTYvS3Jld2VsbGEgLSBMaXZlIGZvciB0aGUgbmlnaHQubXAz" name="link">
</form>
<br>

<form action="downloads_new.php" method="post">
Track Name :- <b>bella vita</b><br />
    By :- <a href="profile.php?id=16">DJ perera</a><br />
           <div id="19">
        <button class="playback btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play</button>
        <audio src="memberfiles/16/bella vita.mp3">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" name="dwn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download MP3</button>
               </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="bella vita.mp3" name="file_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="bWVtYmVyZmlsZXMvMTYvYmVsbGEgdml0YS5tcDM=" name="link">
</form>
<br>
```

This is my html which im using to let visitors to download or play/pause music . Those hidden inputs are used to download the track.

and here is my javascript to play and pause the music . i took this code from stack-overflow question and i have modified it change button text accordingly

```
var curPlaying;
  $(function () {
    $(".playback").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
        if (song.paused) {
            song.play();
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-pause"></i> Stop');
            if (curPlaying) $("audio", "#" + curPlaying)[0].pause();

        } else {
            song.pause();
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play');
        }
        curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    });
  });
```

The above script works perfectly without any issues . it pauses any other audio tracks if user tries to play a new track . however the problem rises when a playing track is paused . it cannot be resumed unless user clicks another to play. then that track(track which was unable to resume) and be played.

however i have noticed that when i move the track id couple of line up like this it play and pauses the track but it will play multiple at the same time .

```
<form action="downloads_new.php" method="post">
<div id="21">
    Track Name :- <b>ai se eu tei pego</b>
    <br />By :- <a href="profile.php?id=16">DJ perera</a>
    <br />
    <button class="playback btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play</button>
    <audio src="memberfiles/16/ai se eu tei pego.mp3">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" name="dwn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download MP3</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="ai se eu tei pego.mp3" name="file_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="bWVtYmVyZmlsZXMvMTYvYWkgc2UgZXUgdGVpIHBlZ28ubXAz" name="link">
</div>
```

as i mentioned above i wrote this those according to an answer posted on Stack-overflow .im not good at javascript or jquery . so it will nice if you point me out the problem . ill greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
$(function () {
    var curAudio;
    $(".playback").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];

        if (curAudio && song != curAudio && !curAudio.paused) {
            curAudio.pause();
            $(curAudio).prev().html('<i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play');
        }

        if (song.paused) {
            song.play();
            curAudio = song;
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-pause"></i> Stop');
        } else {
            song.pause();
            curAudio = undefined;
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play');
        }
        curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    });
});
```

Comment: WOW ! Worked Perfectly . also can there is one little thing . When a new track is played previously playing track's button's value stays at pause . is there anyway that you can make it back to play again ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing the `id` of the current playing `audio` element, you can simplify your logic by pausing them as a group when playing a new one:

```
$(function () {
    $(".playback").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $playback = $(this);

        $('audio').not(this).each(function() { $(this)[0].pause(); });
        var audio = $(this).next('audio')[0];
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play()
            $playback.html('<i class="fa fa-pause"></i> Stop');
        }
        else {
            audio.pause();
            $playback.html('<i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: works perfectly but my button texts wont change . since im new to javascript i have no idea how make them with your code . anyway your code works perfectly :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, missed that part - updated my answer for you.

Comment: yeah i know .. Both of you guys helped me . i have no idea whom to tick . Both of the answers worked perfectly

Comment: It depends entirely on which solution you prefer, although you can upvote us both ;)

Comment: i need two more points to upvote you guys.. ill do it as soon as i get them :) i won't forget it :) again thanks for the help  !!!